# How to prevent apache from running PHP in given directory?

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I use and need *php_fpm7.0* on debian 9 (stretch) apache 2.4.25.
DocumentRoot is */var/www/html* and works well. Php enabled, scripts executed etc... Now I also want to serve the same arborescence as a filesystem via apache dav_fs module.

To do this :

1. */var/www/webdav* is a symlink to */var/www/html* so I can name the same directory with 2 different names in apache config file, and so create 2 distinct configurations based on access name
2. I access webdav with `/webdav` URL. Inside apache config, `/webdav` is an alias that points to */var/www/webdav*. Now I only need to setup the `<Directory /var/www/webdav>` section and everything should be good.

So far, it almost works : I can get and put files, create directories, rename files etc... with webdav, but PHP files continue to be executed when I GET them via the webdav alias. So if I want to edit a .php file, I indeed get the result of the script in my editor, which is useless.

My setting so far :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>

    Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
    <Directory /var/www/webdav>
        SetHandler none
        Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes -MultiViews
        AddType text/plain php php3 php4 php5 php7 php8 pht phptml phps
        AllowOverride None
        DAV On
        <ifmodule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex disabled
        </ifmodule>
        <ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </ifmodule>
        <Files ~ "^\.ht"> # need to be able to edit .htaccess files.
            require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What is the correct way to prevent php execution in /var/www/webdav directory ?

**Edit and Solution**

Since Debian uses `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"` */etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.0-fpm.conf*, I have to use `SetHandler none`. But in the `<Directory>` section, this is too late. it must be used in `<Location>`, this is interpreted early enough. I also included `ProxyPass !` as @exussum suggests (should be placed in `<Location>` ?). It is useles in this precise case, but proxy is certainly unwanted here anyway.

Also note that I had to put the authentication/authorization in `<Directory>`. It worked in `<Location>`, but only the CLI cadaver client could access the webdav collection. When authentication/authorization is in `<Directory>`, the nautilus filemanager could access the files.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    </Directory>

    Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
    <Location /webdav>
        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
            ProxyPass !
        </IfModule>
        SetHandler none
        AddType text/plain php php3 php4 php5 php7 php8 pht phptml phps
    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/webdav>
        AuthName "Restricted Area"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile    "/etc/apache2/user-password"
        require valid-user
        Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Includes -Indexes -MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        DAV On
        <ifmodule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex disabled
        </ifmodule>
        <ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </ifmodule>
        <Files ~ "^\.ht"> # need to be able to edit .htaccess files.
            require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

as your using fpm, You need to send the request to FPM at some point

Usually its like this

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/path/to/socket.sock
```

or similar. (see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM for other options)

You need the files to not hit this have your Directory block use `ProxyPass !` to stop them being passed over

Comment: good idea. unfortunately, `ProxyPassMatch` can't be used in Directory. So it gave me the idea to try in `<Location /webdav>`. There the directive is legal, but does not work. It just happen that debian 9 uses `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"`, not `ProxyPassMatch ...` and so the solution is `setHandler none`. I can't mark your answer as correct since it does not work, but without it I would have definitely not found the solution. So a big thank you.

Comment: +1 because your answer, and the link make sense